# Finding a matrix for a given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm stuck on the following question:

> If S is the column space of A ie. C(A) and T is column space of B ie.
> C(B), then S + T is the column space of what matrix M? The columns of A
> and B and M are all in Rm. (Also, A+B is not always a correct M) .

The given solution is M =[A B]. Didn't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S+T$ consists in all $u+v$ such that $u\in S, v\in T$, we have only to show $\rm{col}[AB]\subset S+T$ (since the converse is trivial).  But this direction is also fairly trivial, because we have all linear combinations of the columns of $[AB]$, since $S$ is the span of the columns of $A$ and $T$  of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $A,B$ have sizes $m \times p$ and $m \times q$. Let $x,y$ be column vectors with $x \in \Bbb R^p$ and $y \in \Bbb R^q$. Note that
$$
[A \ \ B] \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} = Ax + By.
$$
All that remains is to consider the definition of the sum $S + T$ of vector spaces and the definition of the column space.